# Android OkHttp android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, okhttp

я раньше использовал волей и теперь использую okhttp.
у меня много вопрос есть.
почему все вопросы на сервер нужна  runOnUiThread?
и вот мой код:

```
    public class MowzukActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback {
    TextView date, info, title, text, balance;
    ImageView imgAvatar, imgShare;
    Data data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mowzuk);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final Intent intent = getIntent();

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MowzukActivity.this,MowzukCommentActivity.class).putExtra("id",intent.getIntExtra("id", 0)));
            }
        });

        date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mowzuk_date);
        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mowzuk_info);
        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mowzuk_title);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mowzuk_text);
        balance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_mowzuk_balance);
        imgAvatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_mowzuk_avatar);
        imgShare = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_mowzuk_share);

        imgShare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent();
                intent2.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, intent.getStringExtra("name") + " agza tarapyndan ýazylan Mowzuk: \n" + text.getText() + "\n \n" + "Dostlaryňyz bilen hasda gyzykly gürrüňler indi TMChat-da ýükle: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mkurbanov.tazelik");
                intent2.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        });

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("Mowzuk");
        date.setText(intent.getStringExtra("date"));
        info.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name") + " agza tarapyndan ýazylan");
        title.setText(intent.getStringExtra("title"));
        balance.setText("+" + intent.getStringExtra("balance"));
        data = new Data(this);
        data.getStringRequest(Config.topic_get_text_url + intent.getIntExtra("id", 0), this);
        switch (intent.getIntExtra("boy", 0)) {
            case 0:
                imgAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_girl);
                break;
            case 1:
                imgAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_boy);
                break;
            case 2:
                imgAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_girl_vip);
                break;
            case 3:
                imgAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_boy_vip);
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MowzukActivity.this, R.string.no_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(Config.LOG_TAG, e.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
        MowzukActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                text.setText(data.responseToString(response));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.mkurbanov.tmchat, PID: 19940
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1166)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:163)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:489)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:47)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.read(Http1xStream.java:426)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okhttp3.internal.Util.skipAll(Util.java:178)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okhttp3.internal.Util.discard(Util.java:160)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okhttp3.internal.http.Http1xStream$ChunkedSource.close(Http1xStream.java:459)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.close(RealBufferedSource.java:468)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okhttp3.internal.Util.closeQuietly(Util.java:90)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.bytes(ResponseBody.java:130)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:154)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mkurbanov.tmchat.Data.responseToString(Data.java:69)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.mkurbanov.tmchat.ui.MowzukActivity$4.run(MowzukActivity.java:106)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
08-05 13:48:48.437 19940-19940/com.mkurbanov.tmchat E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 13:48:48.477 200-556/? E/ALSAModule: s_standby handle h 0xb8e701f8
08-05 13:48:48.567 196-21934/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
08-05 13:48:48.567 196-21934/? E/qdmemalloc:  
08-05 13:48:48.567 196-21934/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
08-05 13:48:48.567 196-21934/? E/qdmemalloc:  
08-05 13:48:48.687 200-556/? E/ALSAModule: Number of modifiers 0
08-05 13:48:48.687 200-556/? E/ALSAModule: usecase_type is 0
08-05 13:48:48.767 1017-20129/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
08-05 13:48:49.518 196-1087/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
08-05 13:48:49.518 196-1087/? E/qdmemalloc:  
08-05 13:48:49.528 196-1087/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
08-05 13:48:49.528 196-1087/? E/qdmemalloc:  
08-05 13:48:49.738 196-1087/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=3000000 flags=1
08-05 13:48:49.738 196-1087/? E/qdmemalloc:  
08-05 13:48:49.738 196-1087/? E/qdmemalloc: heap_msk=40000000 flags=1
08-05 13:48:49.738 196-1087/? E/qdmemalloc:  
08-05 13:48:51.430 189-189/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
08-05 13:48:53.212 20150-20150/? E/QSEECOMAPI:: Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
08-05 13:48:53.212 20150-20150/? E/QSEECOMAPI:: Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
08-05 13:48:53.212 20150-20150/? E/QSEECOMAPI:: Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
08-05 13:48:53.212 20150-20150/? E/QSEECOMAPI:: Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
08-05 13:48:53.212 20150-20150/? E/QSEECOMAPI:: Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
08-05 13:48:54.433 189-189/? E/SMD: DCD OFF
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

я забыл вот мой код data class

```
package com.mkurbanov.tmchat;

import android.content.Context;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

/**
 * Created by Mukam Kurbanov on 13.06.18.
 */
public class Data {
    Context context;
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

    public Data(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    }


    public void getRequest(String url, Callback callback){
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }


    public void getStringRequest(String url, Callback callback){
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }

    public void postStringRequset(String url, RequestBody formBody, Callback callback){
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);
    }


    //functions...
    public JSONArray responseToJsonArray(Response response){
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }

    public String responseToString(Response response){
        String string = "Test";
        try {
            string = response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return string;
    }

}
```